# How to Merge all bundle files into a single js in angular application using webpack?

Tags: webpack, angular-cli

I want to understand how to merge multiple bundle.js files like main.bundle.js, scripts.bundle.js etc.(5 in number) into a single bundle.js file and make the reference in the  index.html created. I am using angular-cli which uses webpack in turn.

I was able to merge the files using a separate npm module but not using webpack configuration.

Comment: when you say "multiple bundle files" do you mean files that are generated by webpack already? Or files that are part of your project/source? Your webpack config would be helpful. If it's the latter, it might be as simple as `entry: { app: ['src/app.ts', 'src/vendor.ts'] }, output: { filename: 'everything.js' }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You determine what Webpack does and how it does it with a JavaScript configuration file, webpack.config.js. Do this

```html
entry: {
  app: 'src/app.ts',
  vendor: 'src/vendor.ts'
},

output: {
  filename: 'app.js'
}
```

Both app.ts and vendor.ts will be merged into app.js . If you want to keep them seperate do

```html
entry: {
  app: 'src/app.ts',
  vendor: 'src/vendor.ts'
},

output: {
  filename: '[name].js'
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Doesnt help. This is not relevant.

Answer (score 0):

You have an entry file, for example `app.js`.

Then you can have a configuration file for webpack to know what to do named `webpack.config.js` and inside the webpack config file you address the entry point of your application which is the `app.js`

At the minimum configuration of the webpack you can have somthing like this :

```js
// Path Module for relative addressing
const path = require('path');

// Webpack Configuration
module.exports = {

    entry : './src/app.js',

    output : {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: 'app.bundle.js'
    },

    module : {
        rules : [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules'),
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'babel-loader',
                        options: {
                            presets: ['es2015']
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
        ]
    },

}
```

You need to set the proper loader for angular in order to compile your code, for example typescript or ...

And then in the `app.js` (the entry point of your application)

```js
// Importing libs

import $ from 'jquery';

// Import jQuery plugins
window.ionRangeSlider = require('ion-rangeslider');
window.remodal = require('remodal');

// Importing several js modules or components
require('./js/utils');
require('./js/general');
// ...

// Import sass files 
// NOTE: In order to compile sass or css you need to set the loader in the webpack.config.js file
require('./scss/styles.scss');

// AND WHATEVER YOU WANT YOU CAN IMPORT HERE
```

And when you tell the webpack to compile your codes, it starts with your entry point and compile all the assets you included in `app.js` and export a single file named `app.bundle.js`

I hope it helped ;)

Comment: This solution does not help. When I am using angular-cli by webpack.json file isn't even exposed. When I am using an ng-eject to make the same available it is not allowing me to merge the files as the build is failing.

Answer (score -1):

Try these flags

`ng build --aot --prod --bo -sm --vendor-chunk=false --output-hashing=none`

I found that [here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/3288)

There is also an easy to use [webpack combiner plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/merge-files-webpack-plugin) that you should check out, example:

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
var MergeFilesPlugin = require('merge-files-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        'entry1': './tests/test1/src/entry1/index.js',
        'entry2': './tests/test1/src/entry2/index.js'
    },
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, './tests/test1/public'),
        filename: 'all-bundled.js'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                    use: 'css-loader'
                }),
                test: /\.css$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new ExtractTextPlugin({
            filename: '[name].style.css'
        }),
        new MergeFilesPlugin({
            filename: 'css/style.css',
            test: /style\.css/, // it could also be a string
            deleteSourceFiles: true
        })
    ]
}
```

But that would be another npm module which you seem to be against. It is not clear exactly what you are asking as you didn't give examples of what you had tried, or the build commands you ran.

There's also something called [multicompiler](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/4425) you should check out.

```
[
  {
    entry: './app.js',
    output: {
      filename: 'app.js'
    }
  },
  {
    entry: ['es5-shim', 'es5-shim/es5-sham', 'es6-shim', './vendor/polyfills.js'],
    output: output: {
      filename: 'concated.js'
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: This does not merge the polyfill and vendor files.

Comment: But it merges files.. see `entry1` and `entry 2`.. . No one is here to do your work entirely for you